# Parse error for form

Tags: php

I am getting an `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF` at `if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header))` I have close the `semi-colons`. I can't find why it is having problems with the `If` statement

```
 <?php
    include('dbconnect.php');

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        ...

        $to = 'sent@sent.com';
        $subject = $_POST['Subject'];
        $header = 'From:' .$_POST['Email'];
        $message = 
        'New fedback sent by  
        First Name: '.$_POST['FirstName'].' 
        Last Name: '.$_POST['LastName'].'
        about '.$_POST['Subject'].' 
        Message: '.$_POST['msg'].' 
        '

        if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header))
        {

    }   
?>
```

Comment: look at the $message var

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of the previous statement.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: that was the great  to localised close option- now gone :(

Comment: i was more helpful, Barmer just spoon feed Emily :(

Comment: @Dagon - haha ok, what you said, too

Comment: @StevenMoseley thank you, i'll go dry my eyes now.

Comment: Everyone thanks... stupid mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to close your `$message` assignment e.g. `;`

```
 $message = 
    'New fedback sent by  
    First Name: '.$_POST['FirstName'].' 
    Last Name: '.$_POST['LastName'].'
    about '.$_POST['Subject'].' 
    Message: '.$_POST['msg'].' 
    ';
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
    $message = 
    'New fedback sent by  
    First Name: '.$_POST['FirstName'].' 
    Last Name: '.$_POST['LastName'].'
    about '.$_POST['Subject'].' 
    Message: '.$_POST['msg'].' 
    '
```

Is missing a closing semicolon `;`. You need to close it:

```
    $message = 
    'New fedback sent by  
    First Name: '.$_POST['FirstName'].' 
    Last Name: '.$_POST['LastName'].'
    about '.$_POST['Subject'].' 
    Message: '.$_POST['msg'];
```

Comment: Downvote because this is not a correct answer (even with your edits)... the correct answer was posted as a comment and again by jay.

Comment: Yes, but I answered before jay and still both answers are right... cannot see how this answer is `not useful`.